# Martina Bekereja: How to find them in Latvia?

Tags: food-and-drink, maps, locate-this, latvia

When going to Latvia, I like to eat some small snacks in the bakeries called [Martina Bekereja](http://www.bekereja.lv/). I think there are several of them in Latvia, or even in the whole Baltic. Because I really like them, I would like to have a map with all of them. I tried to find them on the homepage, but unfortunately I don't understand Latvian, so I'm not sure if this information is available on there homepage.

Is there any other way to find all these bakeries?

Comment: here you are: https://foursquare.com/search?q=bekereja
I like it too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried translating the site with Bing Translate, but because it's Flash it won't translate. However I did the menu words one at a time, and Vietas means Site - locations, I think. That page just has a number of words with a number after each. If you click on a word, you get a phone number and what are obviously opening hours.

The next step would be to determine whether those words are streetnames within a single city (my guess, with the number then being a street number since one is 76a), or city names. Recognize any?

Comment: They're all street names in Riga. You can find them on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/).

Comment: If you use the google Chrome web browser, there is a built in functionality to translate entire pages if it detects you're looking at a page that has a different language than the one that's used where you are currently located (unless you set a preferred language). For a language like Latvian, though, it won't be completely legible, but it'll get the point across.

Answer (score 6):

I don't speak Latvian, but my girlfriend is Latvian. I'll make her an account later, but for now, here's what she says:

If you go to the "Vietas" tab it gives you a list of street names and numbers of their sites. All the sites are located in Rīga. So, for example, Marijas 19 means : Marijas Street 19, Rīga. Copy-paste the addresses in google maps and you're done.

p.s. their stuff is awesome!

Answer (score 5):

As a Latvian :)

I can suggest a better way to search: by using the [online Latvian Yellow Pages](http://search-result.zl.lv/?QProdukts=%22M%C4%81rti%C5%86a+be%C4%B7ereja%22%2C+konditoreja&QAdrese=Riga).

Because not all are on the maps, which might be outdated, while the yellow pages keeps up-to-date information.

Comment: Broken link. Please update.

Comment: Link is now updated.